# Tag values with time range

Tags: influxdb

Is there any way to retrieve the TAG values with time range?

`SHOW TAG VALUES FROM test WITH KEY = "name" WHERE time > NOW() - 12h`

The above query returns even the 3 day old tag values for which there is no record inserted in the last 12 hours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not query tags with `where`. I think accepting `where` for `show tags` is a minor bug of the InfluxQL parser. The reason is that tags are stored as indexed values and there is no quick way to answer your request (and `show tags values` assumed to be fast).

If you really want, you can try this hack (it's require a grind through database, so it's slow):

```
select name,last(some_value) from test  where time > NOW() - 12h group by "name".
```

To make it work you need provide at least one field name (which you may ignore later). It's a limitation of Influx, you can't do queries on tags only.